# How to prevent Windows Explorer from opening multiple windows for the same folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I'm doing a job that involves begin moving and managing files frequently. As a result, I have several Windows Explorer windows open at the time.

Sometimes, I lose track of the different folders for which the windows are open. Then I inadvertently end up opening windows for the same folder path. e.g. I may have multiple windows open for the my documents folder.

Is there a way that I can prevent Windows Explorer from opening the same folder path in multiple documents?

Thank you for any inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, as it would be highly impractical for most users.

This sounds more like a workflow issue.  Depending on your needs, there is software that may help you.  There are [alternative file explorers](https://www.google.com/search?ei=M0ejW5TJB4ud5wL-xZY4&q=alternative%20file%20explorer%20windows%2010&oq=alternative%20file%20explorer%20w&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0j0i22i30l4j0i22i10i30.8952.9324..12674...0.0..0.91.179.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67.JRK0iSgtmEg) that may help alleviate your issues.  There is software like [Stardock Groupy](https://www.stardock.com/products/groupy/) that will let you stack multiple windows into tabs.  Microsoft is supposed to be releasing [Sets](https://www.theverge.com/2018/5/8/17318334/windows-10-sets-apps-programs-website-tabs-microsoft-build-2018) in the next update to Windows that does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the startdock reference and also for the information about sets. Marking your answer as the accepted answer.