# how to make windows 10's explorer focus existing window when opening the same folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

There is a scenario: suppose I have two open explorer windows, window 1 showing the folder `C:/data` and window 2 showing the folder `C:/`.

What I want is that when I double-click (open) the folder `data` from within the window 1 (`C:/`), the window 2 (`C:/data`) get focused instead of opening the folder `data` in window 1.

I found a similar question here : [so thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1359786/how-to-prevent-windows-explorer-from-opening-multiple-windows-for-the-same-folde) but it is dated from 2018 and not aiming Windows 10. I wonder if things are different in my case.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I have written a powershell script `SwitchOrOpenFolder.ps1` that could do the job in combination with a simple registry hack in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder`.

> **Note**: always make a backup copy of the Windows registry before creating, editing, or modifying any keys or values.

1. Add `SwitchOrOpen` option to context menu for drives and folders and associate it with silent run of the `D:\PShell\tests\SwitchOrOpenFolder.ps1` script (*change the path to fit your circumstances*). This step should result to the following:

```
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\SwitchOrOpen\command"
```

> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\SwitchOrOpen\command
>     (Default)    REG_SZ    mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Run ""powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """"D:\PShell\tests\SwitchOrOpenFolder.ps1"""" -Path """"%V"""""",0:close")
> ```

2. Make the `SwitchOrOpen` verb a default option in context menu for drives and folders (*optional*: maps this option to a mouse double-click or keyboard <kbd>Enter</kbd>); result should be as follows:

```
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell" -ve
```

> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell
>     (Default)    REG_SZ    SwitchOrOpen
> ```

3. Use the following `SwitchOrOpenFolder.ps1` script:

```
param ( [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string]$Path )
if ( '"' -eq $Path.Substring($Path.Length-1) ) {
    $Path = $Path.Substring(0, $Path.Length-1) + '\'
}
$type = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes.WindowAPI' -as [type]
if ( $null -eq  $type ) {
    $sig = @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
'@
    $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name WindowAPI -PassThru
}
$FileExplorer = (New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application').Windows() |
    Where-Object Name -EQ 'File Explorer'
$windows = $FileExplorer |
    Where-Object { ( $Path -eq $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path ) } |
        Select-Object -First 1
if ( $null -eq $windows ) {
    $windows = $FileExplorer |
        Where-Object { ( $type::GetForegroundWindow() -eq $_.HWND ) }
    if ( $null -eq $windows ) {
        C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /e,$Path
    } else {
        $windows.Navigate($Path)
    }
    return
}
$hwnd = $windows.HWND
if ( -32000 -in $windows.Left, $windows.Top ) {
    $null = $type::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4) # ShowNoActivate
}
$null = $type::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd)
```

**Addendum**. The following  Windows 10 registry file `SwitchOrOpen.reg` represents both above steps 1 and 2:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell]
@="SwitchOrOpen"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\SwitchOrOpen]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\SwitchOrOpen\command]
@="mshta.exe vbscript:Execute(\"CreateObject(\"\"WScript.Shell\"\").Run \"\"powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"\"\"\"D:\\PShell\\tests\\SwitchOrOpenFolder.ps1\"\"\"\" -Path \"\"\"\"%V\"\"\"\"\"\",0:close\")"
```